# Barb Whirlwind not procing 'On Melee' Effects

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

[image: Melee attacks throw piercing axe]

I've noticed that "On Hit" effects proc any time an enemy is hit with a spell of any kind. I guessed that 'On Melee Attack" would be similar, but only when the attack is made with a melee weapon. This seems to be true since the axe procs off spells such as HotA and Seismic Slam, though they still have AOE attributes caused by a melee swing. However the axes do not proc when using the Whirlwind ability, is Whirlwind not considered a melee attack?

Comment: Do you have a rune that changes whirlwind from physical to something else?

Comment: No, this still occurs when using No Rune.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific effect that is granted by the legendary weapon Stalgard's Decimator, only procs on resource generators (http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11914801382).

On the same note whirlwind does proc effects just at a reduced rate due to it's higher attack rate. According to this list (http://www.d3maxstats.com/?p=procrates) the proc rate of whirlwind (on any rune) is 13%.

Comment: Exactly the information I was looking for, thank you.